# Change default dot size of geom_point() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

At some release, the dots of `geom_point` became bigger. It might be [2.0](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/): "geom_point() now uses shape 19 instead of 16."

How can I make the default dot from geom_point smaller like it used to be?

**Edit:** How do I change ALL plots without adding code to every plot? That is, the default. I looked in get_theme() and didn't see anything about points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

refer http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) + geom_point(shape = 16)
```

For updating default ggplot geom parameters:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(shape = 16))
```

Comment: Thanks! This will change one plot. How do I change ALL plots? That is, the default. I looked in get_theme() and didn't see anything about points.

Comment: use this for changing geom defaults `update_geom_defaults("point", list(shape = 16))`

Comment: Updated the answer! Thanks.